# Unable copy time machine back up files- the drive shows as read only

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

I've got a new hard drive and want to copy my old time machine backups over, but am unable to. When i open the drive info it shows as read only permission, even though I am the admin of this pc. The format is APFS (case-sensitive encrypted).

Also, i tried to include the drive in backups so that when i do my first backup on the new drive it will "back it up" but the option to remove it from the excluded drives list is greyed out. Here are some screen shots... appreciate any assistance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a specific file you are copying to a specific place that throws an error? I’ll put up a general answer on how I would proceed since I can’t see your setup and some detail may be missing in the first version of your post.

Comment: The picture presented is of the old drive you wish to replace is it not, because the description does not quite reflect that making your question confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behavior. Time Machine puts some extra locks to prevent people from moving or deleting files.

As to your main question, fire up migration assistant to bring back apps, settings or user files from the backup. If you only want specific files, use Time Machine to browse the available files from that backup.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-information-mac-computer-device-mh27921/mac

Hold the option key (`⌥`) down when you select the Time Machine icon from your menu bar to Browse other Time Machine disks and then select your backup drive.

Comment: Thanks for this response. i can't copy past the files, copy is greyed out.

Comment: This would only be for new backups right?                                                                                                
 "You’ll want to make a different APFS volume on that drive if you need a spot to make changes to the files and not dedicate it to protected space for Time Machine backups."

Comment: Lets meet in [chat] I’m not  sure I understand what you mean about new backups. You will need to show us the exact location or path to the file you’re trying to copy. If you use time machine to restore the files, it will help you get what you need. Don’t use finder is my main advice, I suppose

Comment: bmike you may have missed the point on the question, the point was to "copy over the old backups to the new backup drive. not your fault though the question was not well written.